# Viewing graphs in Virtuoso

Tags: rdf, jena, virtuoso

currently, in my application I am working with graph,which is basically a RDF file(creating,inserting triples,manipulating) using Jena framework in Virtuoso. In the server I am able to see the graph names created and there are two options Rename and Delete. Is there any User Interface by which I can see the graph triples or directly take a back up of that graph(i.e. the RDF file) . I know I can upload graph (RDF file) directly but how to view or take a back up of that RDF file?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [SPARQL-endpoint](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-protocol-20130321/). By default, it is at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8890/sparql/
```

Also, recent versions of Virtuoso include [SPARQL Graph Store endpoint](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-http-rdf-update-20130321/) at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8890/sparql-graph-crud
```

Answer (score 0):

Virtuoso has [dump and reload graph](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VirtDumpLoadRdfGraphs) functions that can be used to dump your graphs for back up purposes.